# One off commands on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku-toolbelt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed my first application on amazon beanstalk and am stuck with one seemingly simple issue.

I have node.js scripts that I use to i.e.: migrate the DB schema or populate the RDS with generated sample data. For heroku apps I simply use

```
heroku run <statement>
```

Is there an equivalent of that amazon beanstalk? Whats a good workflow for that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only solution is using good old ssh to connect to the instances(s) and run the statements there. Caveat is that you will need to first create Key Pair first in the EC2 Dashboard and refer to that key when you create the amazon beanstalk environment, you can't create a key pair when you create a amazon beanstalk environment.